# How to Reduce gradient map bleed on hard edges in a GLSL Shader

Tags: colors, glsl

I have a greyscale input image that is getting gradient mapped to a colored image, because of the resolution when transitioning from one shade of grey to another a third shade is created between them. When this is gradient mapped a color appears where it shouldn't.  Ie a yellow band appears between cyan and red.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvvMJ.png)

Is there a way to remove this banding somehow?  Attached is the code that handles the color conversion.

```
//Input Source
    vec2 uv = mm_FragNormCoord;
    vec4 srcPixel = FX_NORM_PIXEL(uv);

    //Output Sources
    vec4 fx_out; // FX output color before mix + post
    vec4 out_color; // Final output color after post
    
    
    //Gradient Colors
    vec4 colors[6];
    colors[0] = mat_color1;
    colors[1] = mat_color2;
    colors[2] = mat_color3;
    colors[3] = mat_color4;
    colors[4] = mat_color5;
    colors[5] = mat_color6;
    
    float greyscale_value;
    
    if(srcPixel.g < 0.01){
        greyscale_value = dot(srcPixel.rgb,vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    } else {
        greyscale_value = dot(srcPixel.rgb,vec3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114));
    }
    

    float stepSize = (1.0/mat_color_count);
    
    float perc = mat_curve * 0.5 + 0.5;
    
    //srcPixel = vec4(round(srcPixel*4.)/4.);
    
    
    vec3 sampled_Color;
    
    for(int index = 0; index < mat_color_count; index++ ){
        if(greyscale_value <= stepSize*float(index)){
        
            float grey = (greyscale_value - stepSize*float(index-1))/(stepSize*float(index) - stepSize*float(index-1))*pow(perc,6);
        
            if(index == 0) grey = 0;
            
            if(grey < .00000000001){ //Essentially Zero but not quite
                sampled_Color = vec3(colors[0].rgb);
            } else  {
                sampled_Color = vec3(mix(colors[index-1].rgb, colors[index].rgb,grey));
            }

            break;
        } else if (greyscale_value > stepSize*float(mat_color_count-1)) {
            sampled_Color = vec3(colors[mat_color_count-1].rgb);
        }
    }
```

I have tried using Antialiasing, reducing the input colors, changing contrast, increasing base resolution.